# Announcing a “Graduation” election for 2021

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Writing Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [an election](https://writing.stackexchange.com/election/3) on **November 1st**, as your “graduation” election. When we ran an election here last year, we intentionally chose to make it a "beta" election for pro-tems but now is the time for your first full election!

The timeline:

- Today (25 October), [I've posted a question collection post](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/2021-moderator-election-qa-question-collection) here on Meta, so that the community can post questions they'd like to see the candidates answer.
- Starting on 1 November, users can [nominate themselves](https://writing.stackexchange.com/election/3). The top questions collected on the previous week will be compiled into a questionnaire on the election page, so that potential moderators can answer them.
- The existing moderator team will need to run in the election if they wish to keep their positions.
- On 8 November, if there are 4 or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period there are still fewer than 4 candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates who've nominated (and aren't already pro-tem mods) and we'll default to considering this a "pro-tem election" just to try to keep the total number of moderators on the site at 3 (for full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections)). (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on 16 November (or 23 November, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.